# Where should I init Git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have started using git, read few tutorials, but I still don't know what is a proper way to use it? Where should I init my repository?

Let's say I have following project

```
my_project
    - modules
        - module_a
            - controller
                feature_a_controller
                feature_b_controller
            - model
                feature_a_model
                feature_b_model
        - module_b
            - controller
                feature_a_controller
                feature_b_controller
            - model
                feature_a_model
                feature_b_model
    - public
        - js
            script.js
        - css
            style.css
```

**1.**
I would like to have separate history for each module, so I should init repository in **module_a** and **module_b**, but each module may have **public** files like javascript or css. As far as I know you can't add files to repo from outside directory, so should I init repository in **my_project** directory?

**2.**
Let's say I'm currently working on **module_a**, should each feature(controller+model) have own branch?

Or maybe I should init repository in **my_project** and each module (module_a and module_b) should have their own branch?

All these possibilities get me confused

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should `init` in **my_project** and change module_a and module_b in separate branches, and keep pushing to master/develop.
Check [this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for branching model.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the repository in **my_project** folder. Make separate branches for **module_a** and **module_b**